# Compiz settings are grayed out

Tags: 12.04, compiz

How do I change Compiz settings in 12.04 LTS?

When I try it grays out all the check boxes so I can't change settings!

Comment: Are you using Unity-3D or Unity 2D? Please tell us about your Environment.

Comment: Also which checkboxes are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

If you unselect the option *Automatic plugin sorting* in CCSM's preference window (in **Plugin list** tab), the options will be grayed out in the main window.

The deselected *Automatic plugin sorting* image is given below:

[image]

The grayed out plugins page's image is given below:

[image]

So, the solution is simple. Open CCSM, Go to *Preferences* Window, select *Plugin list* tab and select the **Automatic plugin sorting** option.

Full credit goes to [jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino), who revealed the information.

Comment: work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

1. try to reconfigure compiz if all packages were installed:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins
   ```
2. If not install or broken, install again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --reinstall install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two possible reasons:

- Maybe you have an old computer.
- Don't have enough resources for Compiz.

Anyway you should try login to Ubuntu 2D and try this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then come back and check if something has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.

##### First, delete the ini files in your user's config directory for compiz:

```
rm /home/$USER/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*.ini
```

##### Then, run the following command to edit your config file:

```
nano /home/$USER/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config
```

change the contents of the file to this (delete all other lines):

```
[general_ubuntu]
profile = unity
```

##### Finally, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

As soon as I saved the config file, my previous settings from the disabled plugins were restored.

##### Lastly, make sure visual effects are not disabled.

Go to your **system settings** > **Appearance** > **Behavior** and for **visual effects** near the bottom of the window, it should be set to **high**.

Comment: I never had this problem on past versions that I remember but it may have been because the first run after the upgrade was without the AMDGPU packages installed. I found them using `apt-cache search amdgpu` and installed everything except for the 18.04 hwe package.